# jQuery dropdown box, cannot make the field value empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In page1.php

2 drop down(dd) boxes - `dd1(id="dd1")` and `dd2(id="dd2")` and other input boxes are there.

When the page is visited , both dds are visible . Drop down values for dd1 are there but no values except 'Select One ' are there for dd2.

a value is chosen from  dd1.

Based on this value, drop down values for dd2 are to be  determined.

So a jquery ajax call `($.get)` is made to `page2.php`. From `page2.php` a drop down box `(id="dd3")` is created. and the ajax response replaces dd2 so the drop down values for dd2 are visible now.

A valus is chosen from dd2 and other input box values are also given. Then the submit button is pressed manually and data is inserted into db through another jquery ajax call.

**Everything is ok  up to this point.**

But I want to make the values of all the dds and input fields become the default ones i.e. no value selected or given.

code used is: `$("#id_name").val('');`

I have been successful for everything (dd1 and input fields) except for dd2.

I think when dd2 is replaced through jquery ajax response by the element with id dd3, then jQuery code in page1.php does not recognize  id name of the dd3  as the id name was given in page2.php.

code used: `$("#dd3").val('');` I used this  too: `$("#dd2").val('')`. But no success

How can i make dd2 get back to its default value?

Answer (score 0):

> "ajax response replaces dd2"

How can you alter an element when you have already replaced it with some thing else ?

My suggestion would be to make the dd2 as Display:none and then apply your logic

Comment: once you replace the element it no longer exists... there is no way to modify something that doesn't exist !!

Comment: alter?! what do u mean? Suppose i want to keep dd2 visible always. Even if i apply the display:none css to dd2, how will that solve the problem? Will the code in page1.php recognize the id name given in page2.php?

Comment: @Gaurav Shah, i used both $("#dd3").val('') and $("#dd2").val('') but was not successful. what is the solution?

Comment: did you try to select the parent element and then traverse down to the element?

Comment: @Semyazas, not clear to me what u say... what is the parent element here? drop down boxes and input boxes follow one after another.

Comment: since i don't know your pages layout it is hard to tell. But usually forms are inside a div/section/etc. so you could select this section by id and get the n-th element like so:      $(parent_by_id).find('formtype :nth-child(2)').val(''); Please note that nth-child is a 1-based array

Comment: formtype:nth-child(2) - please explain each word.. which r the keyword or not?

Comment: You might want to read up on the actual documentation here: http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/ and here: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Comment: @sof_user we could help you in a much better way if you post your complete php code. the snippet way is not helping out .
by alter I mean , say you have an element in the dom and you remove it later on. there is no way you can access an element that doens't exist. so by alter means to either set the value or just read it.